# Will text laid out on an image in Photoshop, when printed look pixelated? Or sharp enough?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typography, print-design, text

The title really says it all. I want to design a poster for my home. But here's my question, if I lay out the text in photoshop, save it and then print it - will the text look pixelated? Or sharp enough like how in posters text normally does?

Comment: To be certain your text stays in vector, you can also convert your .psd file to a Illustrator PDF: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55345/how-to-keep-the-text-in-vector-in-photoshop-without-rasterizing-it-or-flattening

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're sending it to be printed, then save the file as a Photoshop PDF. All your vector information, including text, will remain vector.

Comment: I had no idea you could do that in PhotoShop now. Nice tip!

Comment: It's useful if you're placing a Photoshop comp into an InDesign layout, also. Text in a placed PSD will render at *image* resolution in the printer's RIP, rather than vector resolution (typically 2400 to 2800 dpi going to the plate). If it's placed as a PDF, the text will render at the platesetter's or imagesetter's full resolution.

Comment: *PDF will also retain font hinting for smaller text sizes.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the resolution you create the photoshop files as. If it's a high enough resolution, the pixels are small enough that your eyes won't see them as individual pixels.

For photographic imagery being printed, the typical resolution is 300ppi (pixels per inch). For line art and type, 600ppi is likely a minimum resolution. 1200ppi being typical for higher-end printing.

I'd do a test print at 300ppi and increase the resolution up until you think it looks good.

Comment: I am doing sort of a grunge poster with type on top of it. Suppose I make a 6ft by 3ft poster -  will printing it in 600ppi be enough? And the 'ppi' value, the print company will look after it, no? Or would I need to use Illustrator for type?

Comment: There's lots to consider. A poster that size is likely going to be seen from a distance, so you can likely get away with even lower resolutions than 300ppi. Your printer will handle the printing, but you have to be sure to give them a file with enough pixels in it ;) If you have access to Illustrator or the like, yes, setting the type with that (on top of your imported image) will produce crisp type.

Comment: If I want to print at say - 300 ppi, will I then have to while making the poster in photoshop set the resolution to 300 pixels/inch instead of 72 pixels/inch which is the default?

Comment: That setting just tells PhotoShop how large to print your file. You can change it, but the key issue is that you have enough pixels. If you want a 300ppi image, and it's 6' wide, that's 72(inches) * 300(pixels) = 21,600 pixel wide image.

Comment: Maybe I am getting confused. Here I'll put it simply - if I want to print a poster at 300ppi, will it help that I use the 300 pixels/inch setting in Photoshop? or it will be fine with 72 pixels/inch?

Comment: Technically speaking, it doesn't matter. But yes, you'll likely want to set it to 300ppi just for convenience. If you set it to 300ppi and tell it that the file is 6' wide, it will do the calculations for you and create a new file 21,600 pixels wide for you.

Comment: But it won't be like I'll have to work with gigantic images or anything, no?

Comment: Yes, you will be working with a gigantic image. Resolution of your image = the number of pixels it has. Print resolution = the number of those pixels it will print per inch of paper. In your case, you are asking for 300 pixels per inch when printed. As such, if you're printing your image 6' wide, then you need an image width of 21,600. That *will* be a gigantic image in PhotoShop. (I'd argue a 6' poster will not be viewed close up, so you could get away using a lot fewer pixels)

Comment: And I tried making an image at 1024x769px at 300 pixels/inch and when I saved it, it was still that res: 1024x768px. Please explain to me.

Comment: As for your last question, here's an example: Let's say you have a 1000px image. If you print it at 100ppi, it will be 10" wide. If you print it at 500ppi, it will be 2" wide. In both cases, it has the same amount of pixels, it's just that when printed, the pixels are printed smaller to make a smaller image.

Comment: One very last question - I make an image in photoshop with the settings(in photoshop) width 12 inches and height 30 inches at 300 pixels/inch -  when I print this image at 300 ppi, will it be the same size?...and sorry if I am annoying you...

Comment: This place is for asking question! Not annoying at all. Yes, that is actually what that ppi setting in PhotoShop is for. If you set your ppi setting in photoshop to 300, and then print from PhotoShop, it will print at 300dpi. So your 12x30" image in PhotoShop should be 12x30" on paper.

Comment: I tried transferring a wallpaper I made in Photoshop at 72ppi into a new image i created at 300ppi - both had the same resolution 1024x768px and the 72ppi image filled the covered totally the image with 300ppi, so how come I'll have to work with gigantic images?

Comment: You said you wanted to print a 6'x3' poster at 300ppi. That's a giant image as it'd be 21,600 pixels x 10,800 pixels.

Comment: I actually wanted to know that just changing the resolution(of say a 1024x768px) to 300ppi wouldn't mean I'd have to work with giant images - which I think is right now, no? And thanks a lot! You really helped me to a great extent!

Comment: It is all a bit confusing. The key thing to pay attention to is the number of pixels you have. You need to have enough pixels to be able to print it at the size AND resolution you want to. The PPI setting, by itself, is really a bit of a red herring. For instance, if you have a 900px image at 300ppi, it will print at 3". If you change the ppi to 100, it will still have 900px, but will now print at 9" in size (just using bigger pixels).

Comment: Oh,...yup I do get it now. Thanks a lot mate!