# My first time designing for printing, but printers won't give me any advice or specs

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

Edit: **I am an amateur and it is my first time designing for printing! The printers are very unhelpful unfortunately and won't help me, but I have already paid the money, so I need to make sure I've not made a mistake.** I would be very grateful if someone could have a quick glance over my workflow and offer any help/advice.

I am making a DVD sleeve and a booklet:

- Background images and shapes are prepared in photoshop, CMYK (Profile is U.S.
  Web Coated (SWOP) V2, 300ppi)
- Logo is prepared in Illustrator, (Profile is Coated FOGRA39)
- PSD and AI files (background & logo) are placed in InDesign and main body text is added.
- Barcode PDF is placed in Indesign.
- Exported as PDF using 'Press Quality' preset plus 3mm bleed and crop marks with 3mm offset.
- Acrobat lists the fonts as being embedded.
- The booklet is exported in consecutive order with single pages. Page 1 being the front cover, and the last page being the back cover.

Is there anything I should have done differently or any checks I can do to ensure everything is ready for printing? I have attached the sleeve below. Many thanks!

[(These are the queries which I have already addressed.)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62415/queries-from-printers-about-my-booklet-created-with-photoshop-please-help)

Comment: No one is going to ensure that you did things right without seeing the file.

Comment: Sounds pretty accurate, although I'd export as PDF/X-1a with marks not "press quality". And outline the type in the logo if it's not embedding. And I'm assuming the "booklet" has a page count divisible by 4, and the "PDF Barcode" is *not* scaled in any way.

Comment: Honestly I would outline all text to avoid any font issues

Comment: I have updated my question with the DVD Sleeve available to download from my OneDrive. The booklet is 12 pages and the barcode is not scaled. What do you mean 'with marks not press quality'? Thank you very much for your responses!

Comment: Use the PDF/X-1a preset and tick the options for crop and bleed marks.

Comment: Since your PSD and AI files have different colour profiles (you don't specify which one your InDesign document has), I'd convert to destination (preserve numbers) when exporting to PDF. That way, regardless of which profile you choose, at least it'll all be the _same_ profile.

Comment: We can't tell you what file format (pdf, pdf-x, ai, etc.), bleed, size, color, font size are good if we don't know who is the printer. If you're using an online printer such as Kunaki they might not even accept anything but raster formats. If you're using an online service, they almost always have a specification/requirement sheet online or a FAQ, and that's really what you should trust. I also don't know any local printer who doesn't provide a specification/requirement sheets.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking preflight work and is incomplete. Is it a critique or customer support or "I got paid for this, please-review-my-print-ready-file-service"?

Comment: I haven't got paid for this, I am not a professional graphic designer, this is for me and I have paid the printers already for this job but they sent the artwork back and said there are multiple queries but wouldn't explain the queries, I just wanted someone to have a glance over my revised artwork and let me know if any problems jump out. Thank you for all your responses! I will ask the printers again if they can provide a specification/requirement sheet. Thank you

Comment: By "didn't explain the queries", do you mean they sent you a list or simply refused the artwork? Then why not add the queries to your question. Either we'll tell you what's the real issue(s) or refer you to other questions that already have good answers or checklists for this! Already if you read about print-ready, you know the Illustrator logo font is something worth refusing your files. Plus you talk about a booklet... I guess there's room for a few mistakes in these pages as well (not that I want to add stress on you, more pages = more risks of mistake hee!)

Comment: They sent me a list, I have already posted on here with the list of queries and very kindly been advised about how to address each one. (graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62415/…). In this post I was wondering if there was anything else I should be considering, during design or when exporting - as it is my first time printing and first time using InDesign. Is PDF/X-1a the appropriate format? And should I embed my fonts or outline text? (Thank you for your patience!)

Comment: Can you come to the inkspot chat room? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot

Comment: Yes! Shall I copy this post into the chat? Or just say hello?